# How to force uninstall of broken Wix bundle

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've built a WiX bundle with a custom Managed Bootstrapper Application to play around with it and didn't realize that I had to implement logic for uninstall.

Now I have a version of the bundle installed which cannot be uninstalled.

Is there a clean way to remove this bundle?  I've tried to locate the cached bundle .exe in the C:\ProgramData\Package Cache folder and replace it with a fixed version but unfortunately that still doesn't actually uninstall and it doesn't remove the entry from the installed programs view in Control Panel.

When I examine the MSI log file for the updated bundle, during unistallation, I see some lines that ream something like this:

```
[1014:1B44][2016-08-08T01:13:02]i300: Apply begin
[1014:1B44][2016-08-08T01:13:02]i010: Launching elevated engine process.
[1014:1B44][2016-08-08T01:13:06]i011: Launched elevated engine process.
[1014:1B44][2016-08-08T01:13:06]i012: Connected to elevated engine.
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:06]i358: Pausing automatic updates.
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:12]w308: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:12]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i361: Created a system restore point.
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, options: 0x0, disable resume: No
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {27C17010-A6C4-4087-8EB7-8DCB45DC7D7E}, package: MyPackage1
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i326: Removed dependency: {598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124} on package provider: {C12FA53F-22FA-4979-8C63-0B6850F59A16}, package MyPackage2
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i352: Removing cached bundle: {598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}\
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]w354: Unable to remove cached bundle: {598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}\, reason: 0x80070003. Continuing...
[10F8:1AD4][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{598ba570-f8c8-43c5-8aa9-b7d26f3e6124}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[1014:1B44][2016-08-08T01:13:16]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: One of the main reasons to be testing your installers in a VM environment =]

Comment: @BrianSutherland thanks for your *insightful* comment - funny enough I was testing in a VM but forgot to take a snapshot

Answer (score 2):

[Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_buy_purchase_order_main.html) was able to uninstall all of my bugged bundles yet (it has 30-day trial).

Comment: Thanks @Mischo5500 - was hoping I wouldn't have to rely on a 3p tool but the $30 license was worth the time saved; I was able to get it removed with it

Comment: Spoke too soon - the bundle was removed, but the primary MSI that was installed along with it is still on the system.. pretty irritating